# Can't create .vim directory

Tags: unix, vim, cd

So I deleted my [maximum-awesome](https://github.com/square/maximum-awesome) directory, and now I am trying to re-create the `~/.vim/` directory, by punching in:

```
$ mkdir .vim
```

Then I get:

```
mkdir: .vim: File exists
```

Ok, so I try to `cd` it.

```
cd .vim
```

and I get:

```
cd:cd:13: no such file or directory: .vim
```

What did I do wrong? How can I fix this?

Comment: What does `ls -l .vim` or `stat .vim` show?

Comment: That `cd:cd:13:` output looks a little strange. What kind of operating system do you use?

Comment: I'm using a Mac, and the `ls -l .vim` pointed to the problem. I got this output: `.vim -> /Users/Yashwant/maximum-awesome/vim`

Comment: `unlink .vim` did the trick.

Comment: +1 for the decision to go distribution-free.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible that you have a file called .vim, rather than a directory. Try removing (or moving) it.